# Is it possible to make my own createsuperuser command in django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm working on an app in which I've made my customized `'User'` model which takes email as user name and it is dependent on another model called `'Company'`. When running command `'python manage.py createsuperuser'` I need that django asks me for company first and create company instance, than asks for User model fields in which `'company'` is a foreign key and then user provides company id possibly `'1'` which the user already created when making company object.

I'm trying to implement above by creating management folder in my app, but it doesn't seems to work.

Can anybody please tell me the correct approach to do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Most definitely](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/)! The `createsuperuser` function isn't too special; it just creates a user with the [`is_superuser` flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser) set to `True`. You can write your own method that creates users and sets the superuser flag, along with whatever else you want, by following the instructions in the first link.

Answer (score 1):

Late but may save time for someone.

I had requirements to override the default `createsuperuser` command, After trials & errors & reading the documentation, This worked for me:

1. Create specific app for this purpose.
2. Put it at the top of `INSTALLED_APPS` list.
3. Add the commands layout in the app.

> 

```
management/
     __init__.py
     commands/
          createsuperuser.py
```

> N.B:. the same name of the default command to replace it, different name to extend it.

4. in `my_app.management.commands.createsuperuser.py`, subclass the default command and override its method.

> 

```
 from django.contrib.auth.management.commands.createsuperuser import Command as SuperUserCommand

 class Command(SuperUserCommand):
     ## Override properties and methods to customize the command behaviour.
```

Notes for your specific needs:

1. You may to set `company` field as required.
2. You should override the whole `Command.handle` method to insert your logics inside it (create comapany, add it to user_data dictionary) .

This guide worked for me in `django==4.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, these commands are called management commands and you can write one following guide in docs [Writing custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Asking for user input can be done with `input()` function:

```
#/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py

from django.utils.six.moves import input
def get_input_data(self, field, message, default=None):
        """
        Override this method if you want to customize data inputs or
        validation exceptions.
        """
        raw_value = input(message)
        if default and raw_value == '':
            raw_value = default
        try:
            val = field.clean(raw_value, None)
        except exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            self.stderr.write("Error: %s" % '; '.join(e.messages))
            val = None

        return val
```

Full source code for [Django's createsuperuser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py) can be found on Github.