# Password error when customizing Django authentication

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to customize the authentication that comes by default in Django with a table of Mysql already made (collaborators).
When I want to register a user (with the `command python manage.py createsuperuser`) I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'collaborators.password' in 'field list'").
```

That error mentions that the password column does not exist, and indeed I do not have it in the table, is there any way to indicate that the password is obtained from a column called `contrasena_general`?
I attach my code.

## models.py

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_superuser(self, no_colaborador, nombres_colaborador, apellido_paterno_colaborador, apellido_materno_colaborador,
                        id_plantel, id_area_colaborador, no_empleado_sup, contrasena_general, empleado_interno):

        user = self.model(no_colaborador = no_colaborador, nombres_colaborador = nombres_colaborador, 
            apellido_paterno_colaborador = apellido_paterno_colaborador, apellido_materno_colaborador = apellido_materno_colaborador,
            id_plantel = id_plantel, id_area_colaborador = id_area_colaborador, no_empleado_sup = no_empleado_sup, 
            contrasena_general = contrasena_general, empleado_interno = empleado_interno,)
        user.set_password(contrasena_general)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Colaboradores(AbstractBaseUser):
    no_colaborador = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombres_colaborador = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    apellido_paterno_colaborador = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    apellido_materno_colaborador = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    id_plantel = models.IntegerField()
    id_area_colaborador = models.IntegerField()
    id_centro_costos = models.IntegerField()
    no_empleado_sup = models.IntegerField()
    contrasena_general = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    empleado_interno = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "no_colaborador"

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'collaborators'
        app_label = "journal"

    def __str__ (self): 
        return self.email 

    def def_full_name (self): 
        return self.nombres_colaborador

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.no_colaborador

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.no_colaborador
```

```
# backends.py

class MyAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, no_colaborador, contrasena_general):    
        try:
            user = Colaboradores.objects.get(no_colaborador=no_colaborador)
            if user.check_password(contrasena_general):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except Colaboradores.DoesNotExist:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("user with login %s does not exists " % login)
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error(repr(e))
            return None

    def get_user(self, no_colaborador):
        try:
            user = Colaboradores.objects.get(no_colaborador=no_colaborador)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except Colaboradores.DoesNotExist:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("user with %(no_colaborador)d not found")
            return None
```

```
# setting.py
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'journal.Colaboradores'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('clientes.backends.MyAuthBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

How could you indicate that the password is obtained from a column in the table that is not called a password?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating your own `createsuperuser` command would solve this issue.

Ref: [Is it possible to make my own createsuperuser command in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33215065/is-it-possible-to-make-my-own-createsuperuser-command-in-django)

You can make your based on the the original source code for [Django's createsuperuser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py) that can be found on Github.

As you can see from there, there is a constant on line 20 that says:

```py
PASSWORD_FIELD = 'password'
```

So I guess that since you changed it in the model to `contrasena_general`, you need to make your own custom command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even with `PASWORD_FIELD = "contrasena_general"` does not work, it keeps generating the same error.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo? You wrote `PASWORD_FIELD` and not `PASSWORD_FIELD` (just to make sure).